# Can the latest version of SignalR (Version 2.4.0) be used with MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am talking specifically about version 2.4.0. I have read that it is targeted at .net core only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are separate NuGet packages for the [Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/), and [Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/) versions of SignalR, but there is indeed a 2.4.0 release for Framework 4.5 and later - I've just installed into an MVC app targetting Framework 4.6.1.

However, there are some [feature differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which you need to be aware of.

What you may have read is that the [Azure SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview) offering is for .Net core only.